# Mongodb connection number increase

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, fork, spawn

### **In my program initialization phase**

I have multiple running node processes launched using [childProcess.fork](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options)

Theses processes connects to mongodb multiple times. All of theses opens a total of **83** mongodb connections. It should be all the time **83** connections, not more, not less.

That's fine.

[image]

---

### In my program life

I have a self-built cron system which is launching new node processes every **X** sec. The fact is theses process **do not connect to mongodb in the code** I'm sure of it due to multiple `console.log` I've putted at the connection function call.

But random new connections opens. Sometimes I reach **88**, **89** or even **103** connections when I run my software for multiple hours.

[image]

The weird thing is that the connections appears but never close, even if the launched node processes stop.

Interesting fact, when I stop my program *(all node processes)*, all connection get closed.

[image]

---

### My experiences

At start I thought that my node new processes was connecting to the database : **they don't**

Then I thought that maybe the [fork](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) was forking the mongodb connection as well. But I used [spawn](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) and **got the same result**.

Plus as the documentation says :

> Note: Unlike the fork(2) POSIX system call, child_process.fork() does
>   not clone the current process.

---

Now I'm guessing about either a mongodb problem, either I have no clue and seek your amazing help!

---

### My setup

```
node.js 9.4.0

mongoose 5.0.8

mongodb 3.6.2
```